# I have defined my pointer image and pointer location for my google map. Why is it not displaying?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This is my code: http://pastie.org/3915628

On line 25 I have defined the image of my pointer.
On line 32 for the second argument of function GMarker I have defined the point of my marker.

Why is my marker not showing up?
Am I missing something?
I'm entirely new to using Google Maps.

I apologize for not pasting the code here, but I don't understand the indentation rule. I even indented all of my code in sublime and pasted it here directly but it was only "code-blocking" some of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're mixing Version 2 and Version 3 code. Use the Version 3 code for markers, since V2 will not be supported anymore:

```
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal3/icon31.png",
    shadow: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal3/icon31s.png"
  });
```

About the indentation, what I do is highlight the whole pasted code and click the `{ }` icon in the toolbar. Anything that's four or more spaces indented will appear as code. There's probably a better way of doing the indentation, though

Comment: Thanks on both issues. I'm implementing now.
---implemented---
Sweet, it works.
Thank you so much :')
It's so beautiful